# Building a supercomputer center under a hydroelectric plant

Tags: internal-consistency

I wonder if building a supercomputer or a hosting center under a hydroelectric plant is a good idea?

Firstly the length of power lines to the mega-watt scale consumer is drastically reduced, secondly you can use the mass of the power plant
and the water running through to cool the server rooms reducing
the dependency on A/C.

Unibody concept extended for supercomputers ;-)

The drawback seems to be channeling the water in such a way to
avoid flooding the rooms full of expensive equipment.

Does the benefit outweigh the cost?

P.S. Ancient castles in the Middle East used evaporative cooling
I don't see why we can't do the same minus the water access
to the upper chambers hosting the heat producing equipment.

Besides, fishes flowing downstream could be routed out of the primary
(dam) flow and into the datacenter water cooling passages providing for,
ehem, a safer passage downstream

UPD12/29/2016: apparently M$ had an even crazier idea 5 years back:
https://www.extremetech.com/computing/90992-microsoft-suggests-heating-your-home-with-data-furnaces

Comment: Np, it made the question more focused although I doubt any entiry short of North Korea would test it out to figure out what's the cost benefit ratio is. Current crop of computer components used in the datacenters aren't prepared for an eventuallity "let's meet Mr.Water" unless it's some imaginary data center made of apple watches and iphones 7

Comment: ah well the idea is quite interesting and might make for great worldbuilding, especially for creating secret organizations as they seem to [love hiding in big dams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_Lake); Also I didn't know an applewatch could be used to do anything useful ;)

Comment: Hollywood should pay me royalties if they capitalize on the idea in yet another serving of a waterpunk to the populace ;-)

Comment: Building underneath the dam is not a good idea, as others have already pointed out.  However, it's quite possible to use the lake for cooling (and for heating).  For a real-world example see http://exploitation-energies.epfl.ch/page-112064-en.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Building under a hydroelectric dam could work but there are better places

All of the advantages you listed should hold for a data center built inside a hydroelectric dam.  The problem is that hydro drams usually don't have a lot of space in them for server rooms.

If you built the dam specifically for housing, powering and cooling a data center then keeping the flow of water away from the servers won't be an issue since you're the one designing it.  Besides, plumbing is a very old profession.

### Trade-Offs

If you do build a data center inside a dam, you'll have to work out a sweet spot between structural integrity of the dam, size of the data center, size of generators and other support equipment.  If your data center is too big, you risk making the dam weak.  At the same time, if you make your data center too small then you'll have real problems when you need to add more capacity.

### Location, Location, Location!

Unless there's something really special about building a data center inside a dam, don't build a data center there.  Build it a short distance away from the dam in a giant warehouse size building.  You'll have more space there and it's easier to maintain.  Also, you've build to structures that do one thing really well instead of a single, more complicated structure that has to make lots of compromises in design and build.  All of the cooling and power requirements can be met by feeding power from the dam to the data center.  Perhaps, build the data center on the banks of the river if you want to use water for cooling.

Comment: Ok, so riverband seems like a better idea. You can still route some water under the data center floor and have that augmenting the A/C.

Comment: @AntonTropashko there are in-rack water cooling solutions but those are closed loop. The water to the racks never mixes with river water.

Comment: Right, the idea is using the bypass channels through the building walls and floor. But I guess the issue is that they can get clogged the say way the river floor gets soil accumulated over time in some cases (no influx of water) turning the river into a swamp. For isolated rack cooling circuit there is really zero benefit in water powerplant dam colocation.

Comment: Dan Pichelman's comment gave me another idea (oh now!) building a heatpump circulating water from a circuit under the floor of a datacenter by the riverbank and dumping that heat into the circuits of the heatpump located in the river. Though A/C is probably way cheaper to operate than water based heatpumps.

Comment: @AntonTropashko In general, you want to put connectivity hardware (pipes, cables, etc) under the floor and all the power and cooling equipment nearby or in a separate room.  Is this question just iterating on an idea you had or do you have specific requirements  you need to meet?

Comment: No, being an engineer I'm just tingling my curiosity on double wasteful nature of the datacenters: they consume energy for cooling and operation and dump all the excess heat into the atmosphere. Curious if these operations can be more efficient, that's all.

Comment: Ah, then may I refer you to https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/designing-a-very-efficient-data-center/10150148003778920/  Facebook has enormous datacenters and spend a lot of time thinking about how to make them more efficient.  If you want to know about the state of the art, they are a good place to start. (As much as it pains me to promote anything to do with FB).

Comment: Also, http://opencompute.org/

Answer (score 3):

## Electrical losses aren't very significant

According to Wikipedia, [power transmission losses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power_transmission#Losses) for 1 GW at 765 kV over 160 km amount to 0.5-1.1%. That isn't very much. You can put your computing center within 160 km of your power source and only lose about 1% electrical efficiency.

## Under a river/dam/lake is a bad idea

People don't dig tunnels under fast flowing waters, like the Mississippi River for instance. I don't know of any current tunnels under the Mississippi, but I do know of one former one: the [Hennepin Island tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hennepin_Island_tunnel) in Minneapolis. While that tunnel was under construction in 1869, the river in flood broke through the tunnels roof and basically erased the tunnel.

Fast flowing water is powerful and unpredictable. Tunneling under a dam and lake is not a good idea.

## Water cooling racks takes too many hoses

Water cooling for computer racks are built in units with a heat exchanger, or maybe a small refrigeration unit built in. Imagine that you are trying to use river water to cool your super-computing racks. You have to pipe the water in to the building, split it up with y-junctions to get it to each and every rack, then collect it all to get it out of the building.

This means much more pipe or hose to carry water, and many, many more junctions and fittings, which in turn means much more probability of leaks. Leaks are bad, in that they destroy computing equipment and require expensive maintenance personnel to fix them. Despite the high electric costs of running rack cooling systems and building-wide air conditioning, the expense of thousands of tiny water hoses with corresponding maintenance personnel and inevitable water damage is higher.

## Conclusion

The 1% electrical power savings from transmission losses probably doesn't make much difference, while water cooling is too expensive and building under a dam is too risky.

Comment: I was not so much concerned with the power losses as with the cost of running heavy gauge powerlines from the producer (plant) to the consumer (datacenter). As for the cooling the implied idea was cooling the floors and the walls of the equipment rooms themselves rather than plumbing the water all the way into the racks. Upvoted your answer anyway.

Comment: "too many hoses" isnt' that big a deal. The [Cray-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray-2) was liquid cooled.  The chips were flooded with Flourinert, which was later piped to a heat exchanger to transfer the heat to water.  Some customers used that waste heat to heat their buildings.  Leaks were something to look out for, but they were rare and easily fixed. (I used to maintain Crays)

Comment: A very interesting early(?) application of a heatpump. I mean heating the Cray hosting premises with what outherwise would be the waste heat. Thank you Dan.

Comment: @DanPichelman Copy all. But how expensive was the Cray-2 and how many people like you were paid to maintain them? I'm not saying that it won't work, I'm just saying that there is a reason none of the server rooms at my company have Flourinert heat exchangers, these days.

Comment: water to water heat exchanges are everywhere in the exUSSR, but lets just say its' not a terribly efficient idea to pump hot water across the city to heat buildings. With the local massive source of heat (Cray-2 ;-) it might work better cause the lines are way shorter. No?

Comment: $20 million in 1990s US dollars, 4 people :-)   Most of our time was spent locating and replacing broken ECL (emitter-coupled logic) chips.  Fun times, may they never return.

Comment: how does that compare to nearly $1 mil of 1870 dollars spent cleaning up for Hennepin Island tunnel fiasco? about the same or less?

Comment: @AntonTropashko Construction costs can't really be compared from so long ago. The real cost of the Hennepin Island tunnel thing was that the proposed tunnel never got built, so then they had to build a bridge. Building a bridge costs billions in todays dollars. I image the Corps of Engineers fill efforts would cost billions as well.

Comment: The real watercooling solutions use standing (inverse)radiators between the racks (which are air fan cooled).

Answer (score 2):

Since one of your issues seems to be cooling, there is no reason you could not build the datacenter along the shore of the reservoir the dam has created and simply draw in cooling water from the lake and discharge it close to the dam, where the warm water will flow through the spillways and be used for power generation. Using the water directly for cooling is inefficient, use it on the heat exchanger circuit of a heat pump drawing heat energy from the inside of the data centre.

Building on the water itself isn't a very good idea, both due to the danger of flooding or sinking the datacenter, but also since datacenter are massive structures the size of warehouses to factory complexes. building on the shoreline provides a means to expand as needed. You have the additional advantages of providing the staff with lakefront property for recreation (they can sit outside on the shoreline on their breaks).

Comment: What an unexpected bonus. I wonder what having a dam nearby does to the property values upstream (and downstream). Though in the very cold climates where data centers tend to get built these days you can potentially have lots of acreage allotted to each household I'd imagine. Maybe I should have a sister question now that the picture gets clearer: how far upstream from a water powered powerplant it's cost effective to build a datacenter.